# Spring Data Repository - Method Signatures

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following code:

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, String> { }
```

- Where can i view the methods generated by this?
- Do i have to list all the generated methods also in my service interface, before i can use them in my Controllers?

  ```
  public interface CompanyService { }
  ```

I would liked to use the repository methods via my Service implementation class but it seems there is no way to do that.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking, but (1) you can see the methods by inspecting the declaration of `JpaRepository`, and (2) if you want a one-to-one mapping between your service and repository methods, why not inject the repository directly into the controller and skip the service layer?

Comment: @crizzis i can't skip the service layer because its going to do additional tasks and don't think its a good idea to inject repository and its service in the same controller. This isn't a smart move i think. There must be a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data JPA instantiated your repo for you 'on the fly' (with it's magic )). You can find a repo implementation, for example, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java).

So in common case it's not necessary to duplicate all these methods of your repo. Instead you should add your **custom** '[query methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods)' to it. For example:

```
public interface CompanyRepo extends JpaRepository<Company, String> {
    List<Company> findAllByName(String companyName);
}
```

Spring (again, with its magic) implements this method for you (you can find [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) about how to create such methods). So you will have the repo with basic methods (`save`, `findAll`, `findById`, `delete` etc.) and with your custom methods.

Then you can use this repo in your transactional service to implement your business logic:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CompanyService {

    private final CompanyRepo companyRepo;

    public CompanyService(CompanyRepo companyRepo) {
        this.companyRepo = companyRepo;
    }

    public Company create(CompanyDto dto) {
        Company company = dto.toCompany();
        // Some custom logic...
        return companyRepo.save(company);
    }
}
```

Then use the service in your controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/companies")
public class CompanyController {
    private final CompanyService companyService;

    public CompanyController(CompanyService companyService) {
        this.companyService = companyService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody CompanyDto dto) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(companyService.create(dto));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are all here: [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html).

And *no, do not expose* them directly in your service, your service must *use* them; even if there is simple delegate in some cases (like `find\delete`, etc).

Exposing them in your controller directly, will create a small confusion, especially when testing - since you will need to mock them, test them etc (and spring already tested them). I find it much cleaner when the controller interacts with the service only, and this for example, is enforced in our project.